# Integration of $\int_a^b{f(x)^2 dx}$ for general $f(x)$?

Tags: integration

I working on a math problem that requires an elegant, general solution for $$\int_a^b{f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}.$$ I am struggling to find one and hope that somebody here can help out.

By using integration by parts, I did: $v=f(x)^2$, $du=1$. This gave me the general solution

$$xf(x)^2|_a^b - 2\int_a^b{x f(x) f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}$$

Is there a more tractable way to express this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Seems hopeless in general. You might use Cauchy-Schwarz to get some estimates though.

Comment: For general $f(x)$, this is indeed hopeless.

Comment: If instead you'd have $\;\int\limits_a^b f'(x)\,f(x)^2\,dx\;$ we all would be much happier...

Comment: [Context?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)

Comment: Consider the possibility that you do not require a general solution for that integral, but only a solution in a wide class of cases. Or if you do want a general solution, what do you want it for? If you had it, what would you do with it? It's possible you can get there without the general solution.

Comment: Knowing $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is in general not enough to find $\int f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$. For example, if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log x}$, then $$\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\log\log x+C$$ but $$\int f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=-\operatorname{Ei}(-\log x)-\frac{1}{x\log x}+C,$$ where $\operatorname{Ei}(\cdot)$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), which is proved to be non-elementary.

Comment: You won’t find a general formula for this, sadly.